# Export a MySQL table with hundreds of millions of records in chunks?

Tags: mysql, export

I have a MySQL table with a ton of records, is there an easy way to export it in .CSV chunks with one million records each?

Comment: Can you share why you want chunks? E.g. does the export take too long (tables locking), or is it for further processing?

Comment: A client wants to be able to open up certain ranges in Excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do this (assuming some locks don't bring down your app, otherwise, use a read-slave):

```
mysqldump -u user -pPASS --skip-extended-insert --no-create-info --no-create-db --compact > your.sql
```

This should give you a file with `INSERT` statements per row.

Then use [`split`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split):

```
split -l 1000000 your.sql your-sql
```

Should create files prefixed with `your-sql` - 1,000,000 each. `split` is available on Linux, Unix and MacOSX.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Sweeeeeet! Split is awesome. Thanks Till!

Answer (score 3):

Not chunking it will work just as well, but here's a solution:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'file_0.csv' -- Change the filename here
FIELDS
  TERMINATED BY ','
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  ESCAPED BY '\\'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table
WHERE id BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000 -- And change the range here
```

Do note that you want to limit your range with a `where` on an **indexed** column, otherwise your database will get a *very* heavy load.

Comment: Any way to do this without having to manually change the range for each million?

Comment: You can write a script to automate this (possibly with a stored procedure in MySQL) besides that you can simply export it and split it later. Like Till shows in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4B6Pv9G9_Q0&t=1s

Maybe this will help you. I tried this and it works.

In this video you will learn how to save 4 million rows/records in an Excel from MS SQL Database.

Here are the steps for reference.

1.Export SQL Results in CSV (4 million rows)

2.Download the System (Executable file) from the link in the video description. The system will split the large amount of records from CSV file for you to able to save and open the file and transfer it to Excel file.