# "You probably tried to upload a file that is too large" in phpmyadmin xamp

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have been trying to import Database through phpMyAdmin. My database file is a.sql and it's size is 2.05 GB I am trying to import this on local and phpMyAdmin is saying:

> You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.

Please help I really need this to work.

I read other posts on the forum and watched YouTube videos but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is the configuration you have in your `php.ini` file.

You would want to set/change values of the following configurations:

1. `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` - these limits should be increased to allow the script enough time to process a file of this size.

```
max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 300
```

2. to allow large file processing (buffer for unforeseen usag, overhead processsing, and extra memory usage)

> memory_limit = 2300M

3. `post_max_size`- must be larger than upload_max_filesize because the total size of the HTTP request could be slightly larger than the file size itself, due to the inclusion of any additional POST data. Setting this to a value like 2200M would be reasonable;

> post_max_size = 2200M

4. upload_max_filesize bump it up to a value greater than or equal to 2GB. Since you're dealing with a 2GB file, setting it to a slightly higher value, such as 2100M (which is a little over 2GB), can provide a buffer to accommodate any overheads in the file size.

> upload_max_filesize = 2100M

After making these changes in your php.ini file, be sure to restart your web server (e.g., Apache or Nginx) for the changes to take effect.
Please also ensure that your server has sufficient resources to handle large file uploads and processing.

Another possible soultion would be to split your SQL export file into chunks, when you export it, by using [MySQL Dump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)

[How to export your db in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333260/export-a-mysql-table-with-hundreds-of-millions-of-records-in-chunks)

[Export a large MySQL table as multiple smaller files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112720/export-a-large-mysql-table-as-multiple-smaller-files)

[How to import chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65177155/import-sql-data-in-chunks)

You should also check this post [PHP: settings memory_limits > 1024M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077229/6901693).

However, if you can not export it in chunks, because your old db is not loger availble, it could be a problem to maintain the DB integrity (w/o loosing relations, keys and so on). There are some tools which can help you in splitting.

Have a look at the resources in this post before trying it, to get a better understadning of what is possible/required or needed for your export/import.

Comment: error:

Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.